# Javascript - Ler HTML atualizado ao executar função

Tags: javascript

**1 - Possuo duas funções javascript:**

```js
var linhas = document.getElementById("tabela").getElementsByTagName("tr");
var linhaSelecionada = "";

function selecionarLinha(){
    for(var i = 0; i < linhas.length; i++){
        var linha = linhas[i];
        linha.addEventListener("click", function(){
            this.classList.toggle("selecionado");
        });
    }
    teste();
}

function teste(){
    var selecionados = document.getElementById("tabela").getElementsByClassName("selecionado");
    for(var i = 0; i < selecionados.length; i++){
        var selecionado = selecionados[i];
        selecionado = selecionado.getElementsByTagName("td");
        linhaSelecionada = selecionado[0].innerHTML;
    }
    console.log(linhaSelecionada);
}
```

**2 - O que o código faz e qual é a minha dúvida:**

Ao chamar a função selecionarLinha() através de um botão, eu defino a classe da linha selecionada na tabela com class="selecionado" até aqui está funcionando corretamente. Porém ao chamar a segunda função que deveria fazer a leitura do html e verificar quais linhas estão com class="selecionado" não é encontrado nenhuma linha com essa classe. Gostaria de saber como faço para que a segunda função consiga encontrar quais linhas a primeira função definiu com class="selecionado" sem que eu precise clicar em um botão para selecionar e clicar em outro botão para exibir o que foi selecionado, ou seja, através de um único clique selecionar e exibir a linha selecionada.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite amigo, tente fazer o seguinte:

```
function teste(){
    const selecionados = document.querySelectorAll('#tabela .selecionado')
    let linhaselecionada
 
    selecionados.forEach(selecionado => {
      const td = selecionado.querySelector('td')
      linhaselecionada = td.innerHTML
    })

    console.log(linhaSelecionada);
}
```

Caso ainda assim esteja dando erro, abra o console do navegador e copie e cole aqui o erro pra que eu tenha mais detalhes e possa te orientar melhor.

Espero ter ajudado!